# Does List.Insert have any performance penalty?

Tags: c#, list, time-complexity

Given a list:

```
List<object> SomeList = new List<object>();
```

Does doing:

```
SomeList.Insert(i, val);
```

Vs.

```
SomeList.Add(val);
```

Has any performance penalty? If it does, how it depends on:
 - `i` - insertion index
 - `SomeList.Count` - The size of the list

Comment: Eric Lippert says in http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ **If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then race your horses.**

Comment: @Prash `List<T>` is an auto-resizing array wrapper.  It is not a linked list.

Comment: @Soner Gönül - And if one wins, does it matter why? i think it is.. and i want to know why..

Comment: This suggests that there's a difference: http://www.dotnetperls.com/list-insert List Insert: 6770 ms
List Add:       0 ms

Comment: Thanks @TheEvilPenguin & ChaosPandion. Will get it right. Will remove my erroneous info.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> The List class is the generic equivalent of the ArrayList class. It implements the IList generic interface using an array whose size is dynamically increased as required.

([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx))

Meaning that the internal data is stored as an Array, and so it is likely that to perform the `insert`it will need to move all the elements over to make room, thus its complexity is O(N), while `add` is a (amortised) constant time O(1) operation, so **yes**.

Summary - Yes, it will almost always be slower, and it will get slower the larger your list gets.

Answer (score 14):

When in doubt, perform an empirical experiment:

```
List<object> SomeList = new List<object>();

Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    SomeList.Insert(0, String.Empty);
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
sw.Reset();

SomeList = new List<object>();
sw.Start();
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    SomeList.Add(String.Empty);
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
```

The `Insert` takes 2800ms on my machine; the `Add` takes 0.8ms. So yes, `Insert` is much less performant.

Comment: I think it's more fair to do `Insert(i, String.Empty)` because that gives the same result as the adds. On [replit](https://repl.it/repls/HeavyAshamedForms) `Insert` took 36 seconds, while `Add` took 6 seconds.

Comment: @NickGraham however `Insert(i, String.Empty)` doesn't incur the performance penalty due to shifting elements within the `List<>`. OP asked how the performance of `Insert(i, o)` is impacted by the Insertion Index and `List.Count` and your suggestion ignores the impact of those factors.

Comment: Something I want to point out is you are doing Insert(0, String.Empty). That is why it is not performing well. The insert is less performant, but not by much. I copied your tests, and added few more to prove Capacity, and Insert by Index increase performance. Take a look at what I posted. Also, you should do a throw away test first. Sometimes the first run takes a small hit, so it could give you a false positive in your future empirical experiments.

Answer (score 8):

I realise that this has already been thoroughly answered, but I would like to point out that this information is readily available in the MSDN documentation.

[The documentation for `List<T>.Insert()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx) states:

**This method is an O(n) operation, where n is Count.**

[The documentation for `List<T>.Add()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx) states:

**If Count is less than Capacity, this method is an O(1) operation. If the capacity needs to be increased to accommodate the new element, this method becomes an O(n) operation, where n is Count.**

If you happen to be asking this question because you have a situation where you want to perform frequent adds to the front *and* back of a list, then the appropriate data structure to use is a [`Deque`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deque).

[Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary) has provided a good Deque implementation here: http://nitodeque.codeplex.com/

Comment: Microsoft also has a good implementation of a deque: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

My first thought was "yes, there is a performance penalty because `Insert` needs to move all the items in the list one slot to make room for the new item" -- but then I read the question more carefully. So:

**In general**, `Insert` takes (possibly a lot) more time because it needs to move all the items already in the list to make room for the new item, so it's an O(n) operation on the length of the list (if the list is filled to capacity it will also need to resize, but that's still an O(n) operation). On the other hand `Add` simply appends the new item without needing to move anything so it's faster -- an O(1) operation (unless the list needs to resize, as above).

**In this specific example**, where the list is empty to begin with, there will be no performance difference.

Of course all this is kind of moot because you should choose methods based on what your *intent* is unless you have a documented performance issue.

Answer (score 3):

For an empty list, it is no different.

But for anything else it has to be slower* because to insert at the front, the whole backing array needs to be shifted one to the right.

*Except where the `Add` causes the `Capacity` to increase.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it does.

Since `List<T>` is backed by an array any operation to insert at the beginning of the list must move (or copy) all of the other elements of the array. An operation that adds to the end of the list will occur in constant time, regardless of the number of items in the list.

Answer (score 2):

I built off of Pattermiester's performance tests. When I think of insert, I think of an array, and in order to add to an array you have to specify the index you want to **Insert** at. Doing an Add(0, object) seems counter intuitive. Also, when you do performance tests in always create a throw away run in first. Sometimes it takes longer than it actually should.

### Results

```
2.282 - Throw Away Run
2.6847 - List Insert By Index without Capacity
10544.9766 - List Insert At Index 0 without Capacity
1.8426 - List Add without Capacity
2.0835 - List Insert By Index with Capacity
1.4952 - List Add with Capacity
9323.699 - List Insert at Index 0 with Capacity
```

### Code

```
        var size = 200000;
        //First test sometimes has a bad count
        List<object> SomeList = new List<object>();
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
            SomeList.Insert(i, String.Empty);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + " - Throw Away Run");
        sw.Reset();

        SomeList = new List<object>();
        sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (var i = 0; i < size ; i++)
            SomeList.Insert(i, String.Empty);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds+" - List Insert By Index without Capacity");
        sw.Reset();

        SomeList = new List<object>();
        sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
            SomeList.Insert(0, String.Empty);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + " - List Insert At Index 0 without Capacity");
        sw.Reset();

        SomeList = new List<object>();
        sw.Start();
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
            SomeList.Add(String.Empty);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds+" - List Add without Capacity");
        sw.Reset();

        SomeList = new List<object>(size);
        sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
            SomeList.Insert(i, String.Empty);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds+" - List Insert By Index with Capacity");
        sw.Reset();

        SomeList = new List<object>(size);
        sw.Start();
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
            SomeList.Add(String.Empty);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds+" - List Add with Capacity");
        sw.Reset();

        SomeList = new List<object>(size);
        sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
            SomeList.Insert(0, String.Empty);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + " - List Insert at Index 0 with Capacity");
```

So it appears that the Add is a little more performant than than insert. However, if you are using an Insert(0, ""), you are going to be killing performance that is for sure. If you want best performance, than use capacity.